# Analysing the notion of the native speaker

Tags: second-lang-acquisition, native-language, critical-period

I am interested in the notions of the native, native-like, near native... speakers in linguistics. I have encountered several non-equivalent definitions/characterizations of these concepts. Right now, I'm reading:

Davies, Alan 2003 The Native Speaker: Myth and Reality Clevedon: Multilingual Matters

Paikeday, Thomas M. 1985 The Native Speaker is Dead! Toronto and New York: Paikeday

Are there other, (modern,) important contributions to this discussion? I am especially interested to axiomatize "nativeness" in the context of second language acquisition and the critical period hypothesis. For example we have a native speaker of a certain language and an exceptionally talented, native-like speaker, who learned the same language as his second, third... language after finishing his critical period. Both speakers have approximately the same total rate of errors/mistakes in all aspects of their discourse routine. Can one identify the native speaker by the quality of errors/mistakes? Are there any studies in this direction?

Comment: I think there have been studies to compare the language abilities of L0 and L1 even if the subject is 'bilingual' or learned both at a very young age (well before puberty). But I don't remember the references.